# I am using Cypress version 12.0 and execution time left panel disappeared in Salesforce

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

Using Cypress Version 12 and while exciting script, its working fine till login and password, as soon as enter to the SalesForce application, left panel disappear. I tried with the below options in the cypress.config file: still not same resuly
watchForFileChanges: false,
chromeWebSecurity: false,
viewportHeight:1600,
viewportWidth:1000,

Any advise will be highly appreciated.

I tried couple of combination of Viewpoint hight and width with chrome driver security false but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Please mention the version 12.6 or 12.5.1?
I am using v12.6.0,
in Cypress config=>

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  watchForFileChanges: true,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 5000,
  baseUrl: 'https://myurl.com',
    defaultCommandTimeout: 6000,
    watchForFileChanges: false,
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    viewportHeight: 600,
    viewportWidth: 1000,
    component: {
       viewportHeight: 500,
       viewportWidth: 500
  },
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

Additionally add -> timeout: 10000 like cy.get('.Glts', {timeout: 10000})
or defaultCommandTimeout: 6000 in cypress config.

This should increase the timeout to 10 seconds and the page should have enough time to load completely.
You could also try using a different browser. If you are using Chrome, you could try using Firefox or Edge.